# Android - How can I rotate a specific group of ArrayList items by their values?

Tags: java, android

I'm need to rotate an ArrayList in Android. All the solutions that I have found didn't work the way I need...

How can I rotate the ArrayList to a given position? I don't need to sort it ascending or descending because it is already sorted out. I'm trying this:

```
ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList;

myArray.add("A");
myArray.add("A");
myArray.add("B");
myArray.add("B");
myArray.add("B");
myArray.add("C");
myArray.add("C");
myArray.add("D");
myArray.add("D");
myArray.add("D");

//the above will output: A,A,B,B,B,C,C,D,D,D

String rotateTo = "C";

//this gives me random unwanted results...
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++) {
    String item = myArray.get(i);
    if(item.equals(rotateTo)){
        Collections.rotate(myArray, i);
        break;
    }
}

//the output I need: C,C,D,D,D,A,A,B,B,B
```

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: First Find Distance Of Char "C". Then apply it.

Comment: @Abhishek I see your point... That's what the loop does, as 'i' is the distance of the first 'C'. The problem is the rotate method, it takes the first item and moves it 'i' positions forward. What I need is to rotate the item in position 'i' to the first position in the ArrayList.

Comment: Check Answer Please. Jerry Answer will clear your doubts. Otherwise copy and paste my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Small Change in your code make it work**

```
ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList();

    myArray.add("A");
    myArray.add("A");
    myArray.add("B");
    myArray.add("B");
    myArray.add("B");
    myArray.add("C");
    myArray.add("C");
    myArray.add("D");
    myArray.add("D");
    myArray.add("D");

    //the above will output: A,A,B,B,B,C,C,D,D,D

    System.out.println(myArray);

    String rotateTo = "C";

    int distance = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++) {
        String item = myArray.get(i);
        if(item.equals(rotateTo)){
            distance = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    //you can use distance = myArray.indexOf(rotateTo);
    //to get index rather than above for loop
    //Check Jerry Ans.


    if (distance != -1) {
        //this gives me random unwanted results...
        Collections.rotate(myArray, distance);
    }

    System.out.println(myArray);
```

> Output
>   [A, A, B, B, B, C, C, D, D, D]
>   [C, C, D, D, D, A, A, B, B, B]

Comment: Although @Jerry06 answer is also correct, this answer was the one that worked best for me because this way I can get the index of properties of whichever object I may have in myArray. Tip for reader: I had to multiply the distance by -1 to push the rotation backwards which is what I wanted, so the corresponding object was rotated to the first position in the array. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2):

Just find existed index of `rotateTo` string first

```
int index = myArray.indexOf(rotateTo);
if (index != -1) {
    Collections.rotate(myArray, index);
}
```